# Views with relationship of taxonomy terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

A node (Content 1) has two Tax-Terms (Category-Term 1, Category-Term2). The current relationship contains following entry: `term from field_category` and it's grouped via `field_category`.

How is it possible via a view to get this result?

- Category-Term 1

  - Content 1
- Category-Term 2

  - Content 1

But the current result is:

- Category-Term 1, Category-Term2

  - Content 1, Content 1

Thanks for help. Best C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view FIELDS click on your Catagory field, since your category allows for multiple values, you should see the following option **Multiple Field Settings**, click on it to expand it:

[image]

All you gotta do is uncheck this.

Comment: Terrific!!! :-D