# Hide a row from view display

Tags: views, 8, hooks

I have a view which presents values of specific content type, nothing special, just a normal regular view with a table display. Later on I added to it a field from *views field view* module. Everythink works as expected. Now I need to hide every row which has an empty value of this *views field view* field?

Any ideas how can I do it?

I tried to use *hook_views_pre_render* but in this case I can only get an access to values of fields from parent view not from the one which comes from *views field view*.

Any help will be appreciated!

P.S. The question applies to Drupal 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in a preprocess template function.
e.g.

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_views_view_table()
 * @param $variables
 */
function TEMPLATE_preprocess_views_view_table(&$variables){
  /** @var ViewExecutable $view */
  $view = $variables['view'];

  //Do no alter other views
  if ($view->id() !== 'YOUR_VIEW_ID') return;

  $rows = $variables['rows'];
  foreach ($rows as $key => $row){
    if (empty($row['columns']['VIEWS_FIELD_VIEW_FIELD_NAME']['content'])){
      unset($variables['rows'][$key]);
    }
  }
}
```

Replace
TEMPLATE with your module name or theme name.
YOUR_VIEW_ID with your view id
VIEWS_FIELD_VIEW_FIELD_NAME with the name of your field

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Are you passing argument to the view embed? If true, you should apply the hide field if that argument is empty, so you don't need to control the row on the new view.